# need help finding the name of a series - human character with the ability to dissolve and impersonate others

Tags: story-identification, robots

There was a series of novels about humans fighting against machines where one of the characters had the ability to take the place of other humans by dissolving them and taking their place.  At one point, a human controlled ship took out a machine ship by catching it in some kind of scoop used to convert matter into energy.

Comment: It sounds like it could be part of Fred Saberhagen's *Berserker* series. There are so many, both novels and short stories, and even some by different authors. I don't recall these specific details though.

Comment: Thanks a million guys turns out it was Rings of the Masters by Jack Chalker.

Comment: Had a feeling; that's why I dup flagged it.  Glad to help.